# Mongoose .pre('save') does not trigger

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following model for `mongoose.model('quotes')`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var quotesSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: String, default: moment().format() },
    type: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    number: { type: Number, required: true },

    title: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    background: { type: String, required: true },

    points: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    status: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    owner: { type: String, default: "anon" }
});

var settingsSchema = new Schema({
    nextQuoteNumber: { type: Number, default: 1 }
});

// Save Setting Model earlier to use it below
mongoose.model('settings', settingsSchema);
var Setting = mongoose.model('settings');

quotesSchema.pre('save', true, function(next) {
  Setting.findByIdAndUpdate(currentSettingsId, { $inc: { nextQuoteNumber: 1 } }, function (err, settings) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) };
    this.number = settings.nextQuoteNumber - 1; // substract 1 because I need the 'current' sequence number, not the next
    next();
  });
});

mongoose.model('quotes', quotesSchema);
```

There is an additional Schema for `mongoose.model('settings')` to store an incrementing number for the incrementing unique index `Quote.number` im trying to establish. Before each save, `quotesSchema.pre('save')` is called to read, increase and pass the `nextQuoteNumber` as `this.number` to the respectively `next()` function.

However, this entire `.pre('save')` function does not seem to trigger when saving a `Quote` elsewhere. Mongoose aborts the save since `number` is required but not defined and no `console.log()` i write into the function ever outputs anything.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `pre('validate')` instead of `pre('save')` to set the value for the required field. Mongoose validates documents before saving, therefore your `save` middleware won't be called if there are validation errors. Switching the middleware from `save` to `validate` will make your function set the number field before it is validated.

```
quotesSchema.pre('validate', true, function(next) {
  Setting.findByIdAndUpdate(currentSettingsId, { $inc: { nextQuoteNumber: 1 } }, function (err, settings) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) };
    this.number = settings.nextQuoteNumber - 1; // substract 1 because I need the 'current' sequence number, not the next
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just doing the action in my `pre('save')` whenever actually saving, since it ended up not happening all that often. I take it that if i wouldn't have set `required: true` on my `number`, my variant would have worked too?

Comment: Thanks so much! I had a `required` `unique` field which was not initialized and trying the pre save hook didn't work until I switched to validate like you said.

Answer (score 8):

For people who are redirected here by Google, make sure you are calling `mongoose.model()` AFTER `methods` and hooks declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases we can use

```
UserSchema.pre<User>(/^(updateOne|save|findOneAndUpdate)/, function (next) {
```

But i'm using "this", inside the function to get data, and not works with findOneAndUpdate trigger

I needed to use

```
  async update (id: string, doc: Partial<UserProps>): Promise<User | null> {
    const result = await this.userModel.findById(id)
    Object.assign(result, doc)
    await result?.save()
    return result
  }
```

Instead of

```
  async update (id: string, doc: Partial<UserProps>): Promise<User | null> {
    const result = await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, doc, { new: true, useFindAndModify: false })
    return result
  }
```

Comment: Can use in-built mongoose method `result.set(doc)` instead of `Object.assign(...)`

Answer (score 2):

The short solution is use `findOne` and save

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
user.password = "my new passord";
await user.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where pre('validate') was not helping, hence I used pre('save'). I read that some of the operations are executed directly on the database and hence mongoose middleware will not be called. I changed my route endpoint which will trigger .pre('save'). I took Lodash to parse through the body and update only the field that is passed to the server.

```
router.post("/", async function(req, res, next){
    try{
        const body = req.body;
        const doc  = await MyModel.findById(body._id);
        _.forEach(body, function(value, key) {
            doc[key] = value;
        });

        doc.save().then( doc => {
            res.status(200);
            res.send(doc);
            res.end();
        });

    }catch (err) {
        res.status(500);
        res.send({error: err.message});
        res.end();
    }

});
```