# Pre Function is not called (Using it to auto increment a variable but it's not working)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-sequence

This is my pre function declaration

```
locationSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
 console.log(" HELLO ") //not printing
 var doc = this;
 Counter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'location_id'}, 
 {$inc: {seq: 1} }, 
 {upsert: true , new: true}, function(error, counter)   {
 if(error)
    return next(error);

 doc.locationId = counter.seq;
 next();
 });
});
```

This is my locationSchema declaration, I'm trying to auto increment locationId

```
const locationSchema =  mongoose.Schema({

locationId:{
    type:Number,
    unique:true
}
});

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

This is my counter Schema responsible for incrementing the field

```
 const counterSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
_id: {type: String, required: true},
seq: {type: Number, default: 0}
});


const counterModel = mongoose.model('counter', counterSchema)

module.exports={counterSchema,counterModel}
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141492/mongoose-presave-does-not-trigger