# bcryptjs does not work on insertMany (works fine on create)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, bcryptjs

bcryptjs version: `"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3"`

mongoose version: `"mongoose": "^6.0.12"`

I am trying to encrypt user password on user creation or password update. When I create a single user with `User.create()` everything works as intended (password is encrypted). When I use `User.insertMany()` the data is inserted successfully but the password is not encrypted. This is my schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    surname: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    voterId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    votedFor: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Election'
      }
    ],
    finishedVoting: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  // Only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password with salt 10
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);

  next();
});
```

This is some sample data that I am trying to insert:

```
const voters = [
  {
    name: "Sherali",
    surname: "Samandarov",
    voterId: "194199",
    password: "FA654644", //will be encrypted
    isAdmin: false,
    finishedVoting: false
    // votedFor: [Object], //
  },
  {
    name: "Sherali",
    surname: "Samandarov",
    voterId: "184183",
    password: "MB454644", //will be encrypted
    isAdmin: false,
    finishedVoting: false
    // votedFor: [Object], //
  },
  {
    name: "Sherali",
    surname: "Samandarov",
    voterId: "194324",
    password: "FA651684", //will be encrypted
    isAdmin: false,
    finishedVoting: false
    // votedFor: [Object], //
  }
]
```

I am guessing that `userSchema.pre('save', ...)` does not trigger on `insertMany()` for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was able to solve the problem by following [@victorkt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141492/mongoose-presave-does-not-trigger):

> Use `pre('validate')` instead of `pre('save')` to set the value for the
> required field. Mongoose validates documents before saving, therefore
> your save middleware won't be called if there are validation errors.
> Switching the middleware from `save` to `validate` will make your function
> set the password field before it is validated.

So,

```
userSchema.pre('validate', async function(next) {
  // Only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password with salt 10
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);

  next();
});
```